# prevent laravel link_to_action to perform on double click

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

In my laravel project controller i wrote a code for approve and reject appointments. on rejecting the appointment the entry will be deleted from database and redirect again to the listing table.

i used this code in reject section

```
html_entity_decode(link_to_action('AdminController@getAtoggle', '<img src="'.$icon2.'"alt=asknow width=20 height=20/>',array($data['appointment_id'],2),array('title'=>'Click Me For Reject','ondblclick' => "event.preventDefault();")));
```

But still when double clicks `" Trying to get property of non-object "` error is showing. I clearly know this occurs because , on first click the entry is deleted from database so the second click there is no entry to delete in db. but in case the user double clicks i don't want to show them this error message or 404 page.

so is there any way to prevent double clicks. i tried `"alert"` in `"ondblclick"` but that shows both alert and  error page.

Comment: You could disable the link after the first request has been sent to the server. Can you show us the *relevant* javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're trying to use `event` before it's been initialised.

Try move the code from the `<a>` tag to your JS files, try this jQuery

```
$( "#target" ).dblclick(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm passing in `event` into the callback so you can run `preventDefault()`.