# Prevent showing error when multiple clicking on link tag

Tags: php, laravel-5

My question is: how to prevent application from throwing

> Call to a member function destroy() on null

on user's browser when fast/double clicking on a link HTML element on a laravel project:

```
<a href="{!! route('models.destroy', $model->id) !!}" class="btn btn-danger>Confirm</a>
```

For a similar problem with form submit buttons I used kjdion84's [answer](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/onclick-disable-submit-button):

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('submitted')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $(this).find(':submit').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
        $(this).addClass('submitted');
    }
});
```

But the adaptation I tried didn't work out, either with class or id selectors:

```
$('a.btn-danger').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('pressed')) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('pressed');
    }
});
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243604/prevent-laravel-link-to-action-to-perform-on-double-click) simpler answer, but `event.preventDefault()` doesn't seems to work and using `dblclick` doesn't make a difference.

I'm open to other than Javascript ways of solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to return `false`

```
 $('a.btn-danger').click(function () {

 if ($(this).hasClass('pressed')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('pressed');
    }

});
```

Comment: There should be no space between element and class selectors (my mistake). Also, there is no need for the event argument (also my fault).

Comment: Yes no needs for event but doesn't fault for the " element .selector" i like it like thats more clean than "element.selector"

Comment: Sorry, I agree it's even more intuitive with a space, but I said that there should be no space, because [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5ojaxr24/2/) doesn't work. But if you remove the space between element and class selectors, it works. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure its will not works for a élément with class btn-danger but its means any éléments with btn-danger has à parent as a element. I will édit my response thanks